# Best hook to keep my regexp highlighted

Tags: hooks, highlighting

I need to have non-ASCII chars highlighted in my `latex-mode` buffers. So I added this lines in my `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          '(lambda () (highlight-regexp "[^[:ascii:]]" 'custom-invalid)))
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook
          '(lambda () (highlight-regexp "[^[:ascii:]]" 'custom-invalid)))
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook
          '(lambda () (highlight-regexp "[^[:ascii:]]" 'custom-invalid)))
```

that produce something like:
[image]

Now, some scripts of mine do reset regexp higlights (I need to do that) with the code:

```
(when (bound-and-true-p hi-lock-mode)
    (hi-lock-mode -1))
```

My question is: what's the best way to keep this regexp highlighted in my buffer? I'd prefer something that works only in `latex-mode`. I figured out to use something like a [change hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Change-Hooks.html#Change-Hooks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add font-lock keywords that highlights whatever you want to be highlighted. For example:

```
(defun my-add-nonascii-highlighting ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                          '(("[^[:ascii:]]" (0 'custom-invalid)))))


(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'my-add-nonascii-highlighting)
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook #'my-add-nonascii-highlighting)
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook   #'my-add-nonascii-highlighting)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what you're asking.

But if you use library [`highlight-chars.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight-chars.el) to highlight such chars then you can turn on/off the highlighting provided:

- in the current buffer only (i.e., locally),
- globally whenever `font-lock-mode` is turned on, or
- automatically whenever a buffer is in a given major mode

And if you use library [Highlight](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) ([`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el)) then you have even more control over the highlighting:

- You can use an overlay or text property
- The highlighting can be independent of `font-lock-mode` or controlled by `font-lock-mode`
- You can make the highlighting persist across Emacs sessions

Comment: I'm asking to have non-ASCII chars always highlighted (in `latex-mode`). I'll study your answer.